# How can I set environment variables based on files / the current directory?

Tags: gratis, ubuntu, command-line

I would like to be able to create some files in a directory (e.g. `*.env`) and then have my ZSH / BASH automatically load the environment variables defined in them / unload when I change the directory.

It would be best if a file `~/project/local.env` would define environment variables for all of its (nested) subfolders.

It should be gratis and work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Which software are you asking us to recommend? This sounds more like a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I knew the name of the software I want, why would I go to this site?

Comment: Lol! Sorry (and I intended no offence), It's not about the name of some app. It's that, when I read your question (and maybe it is just me), you don't seem to be asking "what software app can do this for me". It reads more like "how can I do this from the command line, or with a `.bashrc` file, or similar?". If I were you, I would prefer to do it with existing Linux commands if possible, rather than add a new software. If you agree, delete this question and ask on our Linux site. If they can't help, then come back here (but don't cross-post). Whichever you chose, I wish you good luck :-)

Comment: I'm 99% certain that I cannot do it with the software I have installed. It might be only a ZSH plugin, but I need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`direnv`](https://direnv.net/) is what  I was looking for:

- Install via `sudo apt-get install direnv`
- In some target folder, create a `.envrc` file and add some export(1) directives in it.
- the contents of the .envrc file must be valid bash syntax, regardless of the shell you are using
- You have to enable it once per directory with `direnv allow .`

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the answer with us. That will help others in future